# HTML page does not scroll

Tags: html, css

I'm making an HTML page for a project in my subject. The page does not scroll down even the content exceeds the screen..

Here is the css:

```
#main_content
{
    width:100%;
    height: 80%;
    margin-top: 280px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    font-family: Verdana;
    text-align:center;
}

#footer
{
    width:100%;
    background-color: skyblue;
    text-align: center;
    font-family:Verdana;
    text-align:center;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Mind showing us HTML?

Comment: Is that the complete css? Did you style the body or anything?

Comment: Please either post more code, or create a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: can you show you html?

Answer (score 1):

It could be done simply by adding `overflow: scroll`. Here is an example:

```
body {
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the #main_content is the div that holds the main body content and the one holding the information that should scroll, consider giving it a height:auto or 100%.

See if that fixes it

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the contents are inside #main_content, then add overflow:scroll; to it